# What's the equivalence of %g in Python 3 f-format?

Tags: python, format

```
import numpy as np

print('%g'%np.pi)
```

where [`%g` is the same as "e" if exponent is greater than -4 or less than precision, "f" otherwise](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html). The result is

```
3.14159
```

My question is how to use `f{}` print the same format as above?

```
import numpy as np

print(f'{np.pi}')
```

Result is however

```
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Are both versions of Python the same?

Comment: @MarkRansom I use the same version as `Python 3.6.8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(f'{np.pi:g}')
```

then

```
3.14159
```